# How can I add multiple className's to react component?

Tags: reactjs

I need to add one className to a component which is being passed down from the parent, and another className that doesn't have anything to do with its parent, but with the component itself.

example

```
<div className={this.state.className} className={this.props.content.divClassName}>
      <div className={this.props.content.containerClassName}>
      <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
        <p>{this.props.content.subTitle}</p>
        <h1 className={this.props.content.titleClassName}>{this.props.content.headerText}</h1>
        <p className={this.props.content.subTitleClassName}>{this.props.content.paragraph}</p>
        <p>{this.props.content.quote}</p>
        <Button showMe={this.props.content.showButton} buttonText={this.props.content.buttonText} />
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I try this, neither class is applied, I can do one or the other or not both. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```js
<div className={`${this.state.className} ${this.props.content.divClassName}`}>
```

Or if you can't use template strings:

```js
<div className={[this.state.className, this.props.content.divClassName].join(" ")}>
```

Comment: Is this preferred over simple concatenation? `{this.state.className + " " + this.props.content.divClassName}`

Comment: @James Depends who you ask. Personally I'd probably just do the `[].join()` way that I just added, but I'd probably prefer the template string version to concatenation.

Answer (score 10):

Using template literals (Template strings),

Combo of string and props class is here

```
className={`${props.myClass} MyStringClass`}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `classnames` like this:

```
# terminal - install
$ yarn add classnames

// React component
import classnames from 'classnames';

<Component classNames={classnames(class1, class2)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way at the moment if you using css modules is as array. And there you can add regular classes without modules. Here is example:

```
<div className={[styles.restaurantEntry, styles.barEntry, 'alice', 'text-center']}</div>
```

Comment: it does not work for me: it say "TS2322: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Answer (score -1):

`<div className={this.state.className && this.props.content.divClassName></div>`

Comment: Would be nice, if you can write why and how.

Comment: This would set `className` to a boolean. (It's also a syntax error because it's missing the `}`, but would not have the desired effect despite that.)

Comment: Indeed is missing the } , my bad. But, in my apps I can work with this kind of method just fine. I also use ||, and it still works.

Comment: My mistake saying it would set `className` to a boolean :facepalm:, but it is applying boolean logic, so it's not concatenating the values or resulting in both being applied: it's applying one or the other. If both are non-empty strings and you `&&` them, you'll get only the second one applied. If you `||` them you'll get only the first one applied. Whereas the question is asking how to apply both.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<div className={(classes.shiny, classes.round)}>
    i'm shiny and round.
</div>
```

This works with React + Material-UI `makeStyles`.

Comment: I do honestly want anyone with information to comment on why this is not a good solution, as well as those who don't know, to know that it doesn't conform to any best practices. Any suggestions as to how I could convey that message are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please put those parts which are not answering into a comment.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an invalid answer. Only second class is ever used. This is roughly translated to `{className: ("shiny", "round")}` which results in `{className: "round"}` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)